# How to align text to the right while centering it vertically in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of learning HTML and CSS and practicing by writing some HTML for a personal page. I am starting by creating a header with my name aligned to the right, but the text is vertically aligned to the top. I've seen a few examples of some people trying to achieve similar things, but none appear to solve my problem, or provide a solution that appears to be much more complex than what I'm trying to do (align text on both x and y axes independently)

```css
.header1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;

}
.margin-zero {
  margin: 0px;
}
.header1Title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<header class="header1 margin-zero">
  <h1 class="header1Title margin-zero">Luis Argueta</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need a lot of the settings you added since they are default settings (top 0 , left 0, width: 100% etc.).

One way to achieve what you want is to use `display: flex` on the container with `justify-content: flex-end;` and `align-items: center;` which does the alignment:

```css
.header1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
}

.header1Title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header1 margin-zero">
  <h1 class="header1Title margin-zero">Luis Argueta</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

To align right you can use **justify-content: flex-end**; and to centering it verically use **align-items: center**;

```
.header1 {
    background-color: #000000;
    border: none;
    height: 40px;
    /* top: 0px; */
    /* left: 0px; */
    width: 100%;

    /* added styles */
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.header1Title {
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    /* height: 40px; 
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just starting to learn HTML and CSS, I would suggest learning the [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property. It's the easiest way to vertically align elements.
In the parent element `.header1` add `display: flex;` for setting the container as a flexbox. `align-items: center;` will vertically align child elements and `justify-content: end;` will send it to the end of the parent container.

```css
.header1 {
  background-color: #000000;
  border: none;
  height: 40px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
}

.margin-zero {
  margin: 0px;
}


.header1Title {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header1 margin-zero">
  <h1 class="header1Title margin-zero">Luis Argueta</h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you try to achieve still you can independently move element position in X and Y like this using `px` and `margin-top` property to move element from top.

```
.class-name {
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  margin-left: 100px;

}
```

```css
    .header1 {
      background-color: #000000;
      border: none;
      height: 40px;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      width: 100%;

    }
    .margin-zero {
      margin-top: 100px;
      margin-right: 50px;
    }
    .header1Title {
      color: white;
      font-size: 25px;
      height: 40px;
      text-align: right;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
    <header class="header1 margin-zero">
      <h1 class="header1Title margin-zero">Luis Argueta</h1>
    </header>
```